# Detect if I am in master from inside of starcluster plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, starcluster

When you try to add a node to an existing cluster of Starcluster, some plugins can fail depending if you are in master or secondary node.

If your plugin has something like:

```
for node in nodes:
    do something...
```

when you add a node with

```
starcluster addnode myexistingcluster
```

the previous form does not works.

So how would try to differentiate the plugin's operations for master and secondaries nodes.

How can I check if I am in the master from inside the plugin? I tried with the index of `nodes` list but does not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given plugins `on_add_node` signature

`def on_add_node(self, node, nodes, master, user, user_shell, volumes):`

You can call

`node.is_master()`